# React Native Animated.event onScroll scale image from the top left corner rather center

Tags: image, react-native, animation, scale

Hello there actually I've an square image and I've managed that the image gets scaled to zero if I'm scrolling down.

My ScrollView onScroll

```
onScroll={Animated.event(
                    [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset:{y: this.state.scrollY}}}])}
```

My interpolate works if the users scroll 164px and reaches 209px then the image will be not visible.

```
let scale = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({inputRange: [164, 209], outputRange: [1, 0], extrapolate: "clamp"});
```

Here is my wrapper around the image with the transform (scale)

```
<Animated.View style={[styles.image, {opacity, transform: [{scale}]}]}>
```

Actually the Image is scaled from the center point rather from the top left corner, which I want to achieve. Do anyone knows how I can scale from the top left corner with the style property transform? I've uploaded a image to demonstrate.

[image: comparison scale]

Comment: In styles.image try (left:0,top:0,marginLeft:0,marginTop:0)

Comment: @shrutigarg that won't work because the box (blue) in the example image above is the actual <Image />. The problem is that the image gets scaled down from the middle point of the Image. I hope it's clear enough to understand the problem..